# What is a good framework for a soap service?

Tags: python, silverlight, web-services, soap

I'm looking for a good framework to use for a soap **service**. I'd prefer to use a pythonic framework, but after looking at soaplib/rpclib (too unstable), SOAPy (doesn't work with 2.7) and ZSI (too...confusing), I'm not sure that's possible.

I'm fine with it being in another language, though I'm hesitant to use php's soap libraries due to some previous issues I've had with php.

Yes, I would very much like to to be SOAP as this is destined to primarily provide data to a Silverlight client, and VS makes it dead simple to work with soap services. And no, it can't be an WCF service as all of the hosts are linux-based.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout Twisted, great framework for building network services. And soap is basically an extension of xmlrpc.

1. http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/
2. http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/web/howto/xmlrpc.html#auto4
3. http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.web.soap.Proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

I have used Spring WS, JAVA in my previous project. It worked well, without any glitches. We served more than a million API request a day.