# Python Web Service Recommendations

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am looking to create a web service in Python, but none of the libraries/tools I have looked at appear to be actively maintained. I am looking to build a server using SOAP. Don't need to build a client at the moment as I can test using soapUI but will need to write a client at some point.

The ones I have already looked at include

- ZSI
- SOAPpy
- SUDS
- rpclib (formerly soaplib)

Can anyone recommend any more that might be maintained a bit more regularly?

Comment: what kind of webservice? More info - more answers... What features you need?

Comment: @Sentinel - are you sure? There has been no commits for 3 months and the Trac site shows no updates for a while.

Comment: Is three months of silence for a dead project? Sorry but your claim is nonsense.

Comment: @Sentinel - Yeah I suppose you are probably right. Do you know if of any documentation for Suds?

Comment: @user: please take your time - suds has reasonable documentation, you just have to google for it (yourself)

Comment: At the end of the day, if it ain't broke, don't break it, right? So, if the package doesn't have any bug, it's still good for use, no? Look at qmail, for example :p.

Comment: The question asks for server-side SOAP libaries. I think Suds is client-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try twisted: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Its heavily used project to various web services. You can build almost anything from it.

Talking about SOAP here is twisted support for SOAP from docs: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/xmlrpc.html#auto4

Last change was few hour ago - so it is actively maintained.

You may want to read this:

- [Python: How can I use Twisted as the transport for SUDS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671228/python-how-can-i-use-twisted-as-the-transport-for-suds)
- [What is a good framework for a soap service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371139/what-is-a-good-framework-for-a-soap-service)
- [Python SOAP client library using a HTTPS connection with keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832433/python-soap-client-library-using-a-https-connection-with-keys)

Comment: Thanks that's more like what I am after anyway. The server support is much easier, even if there is no stub creation.